# how to escape character in VBA with access for an regex string

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access, escaping

I have a regex string: `.*href="\/anime\/(\d*)\/.*class="animetitle".*<span>(.*)<\/span>.*[\s].*<span id="scoreval\d*">(\d*)<\/span>.*<\/td>[\s].*align="center">(.*)<\/td>`

You can see this regex in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rN8cT7/1).

And when I put that in VBA, some error come.

`regEx.Pattern = ".*href="\/anime\/(\d*)\/.*class="animetitle".*<span>(.*)<\/span>.*[\s].*<span id="scoreval\d*">(\d*)<\/span>.*<\/td>[\s].*align="center">(.*)<\/td>"`

`.*href="\` **`/`** `anime` Is the first error, but I can't understand that. Maybe some `"` are the problem. But what about the `\` who is normally escape that character.

Comment: use \\ whereever there is \

Comment: same error if I do that: `.*href="\\/anime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in VBA you have to escape the string-delimiter (`"`) by doubling it. So:

```
regEx.Pattern = ".*href=""\/anime\/(\d*)\/.*class=""animetitle"".*<span>(.*)<\/span>.*[\s].*<span id=""scoreval\d*"">(\d*)<\/span>.*<\/td>[\s].*align=""center"">(.*)<\/td>"
```

As a side note, I would discourage you from using regexes to parse HTML. [This website](http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html) explains why and offers alternatives in some languages. If there's a HTML-parser for VBA, I would encourage you to use that in stead :)